# How to open an app via Intent and clear the back stack to return to app

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like that when i open an app via android intent, when the user presses the back button, it will return to my app. Currently, if using the bellow code, it opens the app but when pressing the back button it returns to app main page and only after a second press return to my app.

```
private void openApp(String packageName) {
        Intent launchIntent = mContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (launchIntent != null) {
            mContext.startActivity(launchIntent); 
        } 
    }
```

Looking online i checked guides such as:

[Understand Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack)

I also played and checked android source code  for Intent flags and actions but could not figure our how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Your app can't control the workflow/ navigation behavior of another app. Once you start the other app, you have no further control of the user's navigation options until the user returns to your app.

By the way, the behavior you describe is the appropriate behavior for e.g. an app which offers an implicit [deep link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link):

> This means that when a user presses the Back button from a deep link destination, they navigate back up the navigation stack just as though they entered your app from its entry point.

Comment: Not sure who down voted you. Sounds like the answer i was looking for. I will look into the "deep link" since i am not sure if still something i can do to resolve it. Thx.

Comment: @Ran - well, maybe someone thinks I'm wrong. Of course in this case they might help you with your problem either by writing their own answer or by pointing out to me (and you) in which way I am wrong. But I understand if they are reluctant to do so. That being said, I tried to tell you that there is nothing you can do to force some third party app to finish itself once it has been started. I'm sure my app would be uninstalled very fast but I might for example override onBackPressed() in my Activity to inhibit the normal function of the BACK button.